# Sometime double quotes disappear when write to csv file

Tags: java, file, export-to-csv, writefile, jackson-dataformat-csv

I am writing my data to csv file in java. Below is my code

```
    public static void writeAccountToFile(List<Map<String, Object>> list, String filePath) {
        System.out.println("Write data to csv file start");
        try {
            File file = new File(filePath);
            Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file), "UTF-8");
            CsvSchema schema = null;
            CsvSchema.Builder schemaBuilder = CsvSchema.builder();
            if (list != null && !list.isEmpty()) {
                for (String col : list.get(0).keySet()) {
                    schemaBuilder.addColumn(col);
                }
                schema = schemaBuilder.build().withLineSeparator("\r").withHeader();
            }

            CsvMapper mapper = new CsvMapper();
            mapper.writer(schema).writeValues(writer).writeAll(list);
            writer.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Write data to csv file end");
    }
```

When I check my result file, last line there is no "" in accountName test3 and test4.

```
accountId,accountName,address
1111,"test1111111",england
2222,"test222222222",tokyo
3333,test3,italy
4444,test4,indo
```

Here is my input list:

```
[{accountId=1111, accountName=test1111111, address=england}, {accountId=2222, 
accountName=test222222222, address=tokyo}, {accountId=3333, accountName=test3, 
address=italy}, {accountId=4444, accountName=test4, 
address=indo}]
```

Here is my code to read csv file and assign it to list:

```
public static List<Map<String, Object>> loadFileAccount(String filePath) throws Exception {
    List<Map<String, Object>> list = new ArrayList<>();
    removeBom(Paths.get(filePath));
    System.out.println("Load account data from csv start");
    File file = new File(filePath);
    Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "UTF-8");
    Iterator<Map<String, Object>> iterator = new CsvMapper()
            .readerFor(Map.class)
            .with(CsvSchema.emptySchema().withHeader())
            .readValues(reader);
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Map<String, Object> keyVals = iterator.next();
        list.add(keyVals);
    }

    reader.close();
    System.out.println("Load account data from csv end");
    return list;
}
```

What is error in my code?

Comment: I tried your code, works fine, can you add the code where you create the List of Maps? I suspect the values in the map are the issue, not the writing to file.

Comment: @Bentaye I added code to create the list of map.

Comment: `.withLineSeparator("\r")` raised my suspicion as  that is very old MacOS line ending. Windows would be `"\r\n"`.

Comment: @JoopEggen I add \n but It still lost "" at test3

Comment: It seems that the length of test3 is small so it has not ""

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are right, when the String is long, it adds quotes.
So to avoid inconsistencies, you can specify if you want quotes or not using
`CsvGenerator.Feature.ALWAYS_QUOTE_STRINGS` or `CsvGenerator.Feature.STRICT_CHECK_FOR_QUOTING`

This will always add double quotes:

```
CsvMapper mapper = new CsvMapper();
mapper.configure(CsvGenerator.Feature.ALWAYS_QUOTE_STRINGS, true);
mapper.writer(schema).writeValues(writer).writeAll(list);
```

The other one should never add double quotes